# Angular with Redux triggering change detection

Tags: javascript, angular, redux

I'm new to Redux so I'm sure this is something I'm missing, but I have a component that is subscribing to a Redux store, which is an observable of an array of objects. The problem is that even though a single property is changing on one of the objects, I'm returning a copy of the object, so Angular thinks everything changed and triggers a redraw. This would be fine except that my component has CSS transitions that don't get fired correctly because they should only react to the property change and now be removed and added again. Here's a simple example (pseudo code)

```
const state = {
    items: [ 
      {
        open: false,
      },
      {
        open: true,
      }
     ]
   }
```

Then a component is something like:

```
<div *ngFor='for let item of items'>
  <div @openClose='item.open'>Some stuff</div>
</div>
```

So when my store sets the open property from true to false, instead of closing my component through a triggered animation, it simply redraws each div.

This must be a common problem, so is there an accepted way to set this up so the component is only created once?

Comment: There is a lot of ground to cover here.  Please provide either a stackblitz or plunker replicating your specific scenario, or perhaps a github repo of your work with details as to what behaviour is expected over what is happening and in what component(s).

Comment: I'll try, but the repo is private so I'll need to create an example from scratch. This seems like a problem that almost everyone will encounter if they combine Angular with Redux, though.